# Advise on new project - scheduling board

Tags: html, gridview

I'm about to embark on a prototype of a schedule viewer. It will need to support about 100 resources (rows) and show at least 12 weeks of jobs with a resolution of 1 hour. Should look something like this:

http://icahn.mssm.edu/static_files/MSSM/Images/Departments/Psychiatry/Programs%20and%20Services/Education/Psychiatry%20Residency/Schedule.png

Long term, it may support  updating via drag and drop.

I use visual studio a lot and vb and c# (asp.net and recently lightswitch 2013). Don't have much graphics handling experience and little java, as I hate the debugging capabilities.

My gut feeling, given the trends in the market, is HTML 5, but not sure weather to use asp.net, java, etc. and whether to build from scratch in pure HTML or try and find some sort of Grid control as the basis

Would welcome any suggestions

Regards

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Go with html5 and Asp.net MVC. Stay away from web forms